# how to move the libraries from module path to classpath?

Tags: javafx

I've installed eclips ide .i'm creating a javaFx project and starting it but don't know why after following all steps of installation and setup. I'm getting Error : `Module javafx.controls not found`
I've folllowed this video tutorial : https://youtu.be/9XJicRt_FaI?t=33

I've done everything exact from the video But I've noticed that In  "cofigure-build-path"
AS PER VIDEO : **ModulePath** -> JRE System Librery [javaSE-17] **Classpath** ->   JavaFx, JAVA SDK
IN MY IDE    : **ModulePath**->javaFX SDK , JRE System Librery [javaSE-17]  **Classpath** -> javaFx

Java SDK  is in modulepath in my ide so how do I move it from my module path to class path

i've searched this error but there is only vm arguments related solution which i've set exactly as video and i found no errors related  that but still if any stuggestion are there they are welcomed.

Comment: FX modules __must be__ on the module path btw: prefer official doc like https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ over dubiose videos for learning

Comment: To make things easier on yourself, you might want to consider using a JDK that includes JavaFX. Two distributions I know of that include JavaFX are BellSoft Liberica ("Full JDK") and Azul Zulu ("JDK FX").